# select top rows based on value in Parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008

i would like to select TOP rows from a stored procedure.The number of rows to be selected has a parameter of a stroed proc.
something like this:

```
declare @rowCount int 
SET @rowCount = 5
select top @rowCount * from ActivityLog
```

this doesn't execute, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: TOP without ORDER BY? Also what does "doesn't execute" mean? Did you try `TOP (@RowCount)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `top()`

```
select top (@rowCount) * from ActivityLog
```